# How to formulate if-then for two sums in an integer program

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, integer-programming, logical-constraints

I have two sets of Boolean variables, $x_1, \dots, x_n$ and $y_1, \dots, y_m$ and a positive integer $b$. I would like to add the constraint:

$$\text{If }\sum_i x_i = b  \text{ then }\sum_i y_i > b$$

How can you formulate this as an integer program?

I have seen similar looking questions but as a beginner in OR I can't tell if they apply directly to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formulation by @joni is correct (+1) but can simplified and modified to use only two new binary variables, as follows.  The second $\le$ in $(1)$ is not needed, and the first $\le$ can be replaced with
$$(b+1)w_2 \le \sum_i y_i \tag6$$
Now $z_1$ and $(5)$ are no longer needed. You can also eliminate $w_2$, as @joni suggested.  Think of $w_2$ as a slack variable for $(4)$, and substitute $w_2=1-w_1-w_3$ throughout, yielding only three constraints:
\begin{align}
(b+1)(1-w_1-w_3)&\le \sum_i y_i \tag7 \\
b-b w_1+w_3\le\sum_i x_i&\le b-w_1+(n-b)w_3 \tag8 \\
w_1+w_3&\le 1 \tag9
\end{align}

Comment: That's very clever, thank you.  I am now wondering which formulation will be most effective for an integer programming solver.

Comment: I wouldn’t expect much difference, but it is worth trying both for comparison.

Comment: @RobPratt, Would you please, is there any reason to don't use the original form of the original expression instead of using contraposition? for example, $\sum_{i} x_{i} = bz$, where $z$ is a binary variable, and adding appropriate corresponding constraints for applying the second part?

Comment: @A.Omidi The choices for $\sum_i x_i$ should be $=b$ and $\not=b$, but your proposal would instead yield $=b$ and $=0$, which is too restrictive.

Comment: Is it any simpler if we are separately guaranteed that neither $\sum y_i$ nor $\sum x_i$ can be less than $b$ unless they equal $0$?

Comment: So $\sum x_i \in\{0,b,b+1,\dots,n\}$ and $\sum y_i \in\{0,b,b+1,\dots,m\}$?  Just based on $\sum x_i$, you could then strengthen $(8)$ by replacing the $-w_1$ in the second part with $-b w_1$.  By the way, what do $x_i$ and $y_i$ represent in your problem?

Comment: Yes that's exactly right. I am afraid I am not solving an important problem. I just made up a puzzle for myself so I could learn about integer programming.

Comment: @RobPratt, Dear Dr Pratt, thanks for your answer. 

Answer (score 5):

Your constraint is equivalent to the contraposition

$$
\sum_i y_i \leq b \implies \sum_i x_i \neq b.
$$

By introducing additional binary variables $z_1, w_1, w_2, w_3$, it can be formulated as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
(b+1) (1-z_1)  &\leq \sum_i y_i \leq b z_1 + m (1-z_1) \tag{1} \\
b w_2 + (b+1) w_3 &\leq \sum_i x_i \leq (b-1)w_1 + b \cdot w_2 + n \cdot w_3, \tag{2}\\
w_1 + w_2 + w_3 &= 1, \tag{4}\\
z_1 &\leq w_1 + w_3 \tag{5}.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if there is a proof that 4 is the minimum number of new binary variables you have to introduce?

Comment: In this formulation, you need at least three new binary variables. Note that you can eliminate one variable by substituting (4) into (2).

Answer (score 3):

With many solvers like CPLEX you can directly write logical constraints.

For instance with OPL CPLEX

```
int n=5;
int m=4;
int b=2;

dvar boolean x[1..n];
dvar boolean y[1..m];

subject to
{
  (b==sum(i in 1..n) x[i]) => (b<=-1+sum(i in 1..m) y[i]);
}
```

works fine

Comment: Do you know if this built in method will typically be more/less efficient than the clever formulation from https://or.stackexchange.com/a/8398/9631 ?

Comment: I don't know CPLEX but it looks like you have defined the $x_i$ to be Booleans but the $y_i$ to be positive integers? Why not have the $y_i$ as Booleans too?

Comment: Hi, I just changed y to boolean too